# How to put NSDictionary inside NSDictionary into UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I receive following NSDictionary from my server. I don't know how to access each row and put them in UITableView. I need a for loop or something to access each of them one by one:  I get following when I say:

```
NSLog(@"%@",dict);

{
    chores =     (
                {
            "first_due_date" = "2016-03-12";
            frequency = weekly;
            id = 1;
            name = TEST;
            parent = Blah;
            "previous_chores" =             (
            );
        },
                {
            "first_due_date" = "2016-03-12";
            frequency = weekly;
            id = 2;
            name = TEST2;
            parent = Blah;
            "previous_chores" =             (
            );
        },
                {
            "first_due_date" = "2016-03-12";
            frequency = weekly;
            id = 3;
            name = TEST3;
            parent = Blah;
            "previous_chores" =             (
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can directly use the array without split it like following:

Suppose you have an array with dictionary and inside the dictionary as your data and kiran said:

```
NSArray *arrChores = [dict valueForKey @"Chores"];
```

Your array look like 0th index is:

```
  {
            "first_due_date" = "2016-03-12";
            frequency = weekly;
            id = 1;
            name = TEST;
            parent = Blah;
            "previous_chores" =             (
            );
  }
```

so you can print the name like following in cellForrowIndex:

```
 NSLog(@"=== %@",[[arrChores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"])
```

More easy and less maintain :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for Chores.

Looking at the dictionary.

**Chores** is an array consisting of dictionaries in it.

So you can have array like this

```
arrChoresGlobal = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *arrChores = [dict valueForKey @"Chores"];
```

Then iterate this array and have a model.

like below

```
for(NSDictionary *dctChore in arrChores)
{
    SomeModel *obj = [SomeModel new];
    obj.first_due_date = [dctChore valueForKey:@"first_due_date"];
    [arrChoresGlobal addObject:obj];
}
```

Then use this array count in numberOfRows in tableview

```
return [arrChoresGlobal count];
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
SomeModel *obj = [arrChoresGlobal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Edit :- Longer but systematic way :)